# (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main' and undefined reference to function

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors, makefile

I am having issue getting my makefile to work without errors. The first issue i have is with an undefined reference to main. I have main in my producer.c file as a function. The second issue is an undefined reference to SearchCustomer().

error:

```
bash-4.1$ make
gcc -Wall -c producer.c shared.h
gcc -Wall -c consumer.c shared.h
gcc -Wall -c AddRemove.c shared.h
gcc -pthread -Wall -o producer.o consumer.o AddRemove.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
AddRemove.o: In function `AddRemove':
AddRemove.c:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `SearchCustomer'
AddRemove.c:(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to `SearchCustomer'
AddRemove.c:(.text+0x351): undefined reference to `SearchCustomer'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [producer] Error 1
```

makefile:

```
COMPILER = gcc
CCFLAGS = -Wall
all: main

debug:
    make DEBUG=TRUE


main: producer.o consumer.o AddRemove.o
    $(COMPILER) -pthread $(CCFLAGS) -o producer.o consumer.o AddRemove.o
producer.o: producer.c shared.h
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c producer.c shared.h
consumer.o: consumer.c shared.h
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c consumer.c shared.h
AddRemove.o: AddRemove.c shared.h
    $(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c AddRemove.c shared.h


ifeq ($(DEBUG), TRUE)
    CCFLAGS += -g
endif

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Comment: The code is **too** long. Narrow your problem down and provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: A couple of suggestions: in the `main` recipe, you can write: `$(COMPILER) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)` and put `-pthread` in `LDFLAGS`. In the other rules you can write **once**: `%.o: %.c` and as recipe: `$(COMPILER) $(CCFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<` (and **not** give the `.h` to the compiler!) and later add dependency for special targets, for example: `producer.o: shared.h other_header.h` and `consumer.o: shared.h yet_another_header.h` etc.

Comment: A couple other suggestions: Use `$(MAKE)` instead of just `make` to keep the command line flags for the invoked make. You may also want to give `--no-print-directory` to prevent couple lines of useless output. Also, use `CFLAGS` for C (instead of `CCFLAGS` which could be mistaken for C++).

Comment: And more: Add `.PHONY: all clean debug` and other targets that are not actually files, to let `make` know that it shouldn't expect an actual file to come out of the recipe. You can also use `@$(MAKE) DEBUG=TRUE` (adding `@`) to prevent make from echoing the command.

Comment: And finally, you can benefit from reading the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This rule

```
main: producer.o consumer.o AddRemove.o
   $(COMPILER) -pthread $(CCFLAGS) -o producer.o consumer.o AddRemove.o
```

is wrong. It says to create a file named producer.o (with `-o producer.o`), but you want to create a file named `main`. Please excuse the shouting, but **ALWAYS USE $@ TO REFERENCE THE TARGET**:

```
main: producer.o consumer.o AddRemove.o
   $(COMPILER) -pthread $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ producer.o consumer.o AddRemove.o
```

As Shahbaz rightly points out, the gmake professionals would also use `$^` which expands to all the prerequisites in the rule. In general, if you find yourself repeating a string or name, you're doing it wrong and should use a variable, whether one of the built-ins or one you create.

```
main: producer.o consumer.o AddRemove.o
   $(COMPILER) -pthread $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Also use `$^` to refer to all dependencies of it.

Answer (score 7):

This error means that, while linking, compiler is not able to find the definition of `main()` function anywhere.

In your makefile, the `main` rule will expand to something like this.

```
main: producer.o consumer.o AddRemove.o
   gcc -pthread -Wall -o producer.o consumer.o AddRemove.o
```

As per the `gcc` [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc), the use of `-o` switch is as below

> -o *file*      Place output in file *file*. This applies regardless to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable
>   file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.  If `-o`
>   is not specified, the default is to put an executable file in `a.out`.

It means, gcc will put the output in the filename provided immediate next to `-o` switch. So, here instead of linking all the `.o` files together and creating the binary [`main`, in your case], its creating the binary as `producer.o`, linking the other `.o` files. Please correct that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possible bug that could lead to this error:

I had some code in a namespace, so my header file looked like
`namespace MY_NAMESPACE { ... }`

In the c file, I foolishly did this same thing, writing `namespace MY_NAMESPACE { ... main() ... }`.

On compilation, it failed with the given error. Instead, I changed the code in my c file to `using namespace MY_NAMESPACE {... main() ...}`. This worked because now, instead of writing main to a distinct namespace, it was just using definitions from another namespace.