# what does (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main' mean

Tags: c++, linker-errors

Could someone help me with the error that I am getting in the code listing below?

The error is, most likely, about the constructor/destructor:

> /usr/bin/ld:
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in
>   function `_start':
>
> (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Code listing:

```
                         // counter_id.cpp
                        // Obco class member-function  definitions.
   #include <iostream>

   #include "counter_id.h"  // include counter class definition

   using namespace std;

    // constructor sets object's ID number and descriptive message
   Obco::Obco( int ID, string messageString )
  : objectID( ID ), message( messageString )
     {
   cout << "Object " << objectID << "constructor runs"
     << message << endl;
     } // end CreateAndDestroy constructor


     // destructor
    Obco::~Obco()
   {
   // output newline for certain objects; helps readability
     cout << ( objectID == 1 || objectID == 6 ? "\n" : "" );
     cout << "Object " << objectID << " destructor runs "
     << message << endl;
       } // end ~Obco destructor
```

Comment: It means you tried to link an executable without a `main()` method.

Comment: And their is exactly nothing in the error message to suggest it is about the constructor or destructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(.text+0x20): undefined reference to \`main' and undefined reference to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20514587/text0x20-undefined-reference-to-main-and-undefined-reference-to-function). There are more than 8000 existing posts related to this error according to a [basic search of the site for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=undefined+reference+to+main).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not just separately compiling (-c), you're trying to do a full link but the linker hasn't found any `main` function.

For a complete link you need to include all your source or object files in your `g++` invocation (especially the one with your `main` function).

For separately compiling just your one file (to be linked later) you need to add the `-c` option.

Comment: thank you!, that really work .  i compiled together g++ main_counter_id.cpp counter_id.cpp -o main_counter_id